How to write an elisp function for converting org files to html with custom classes defined by property?
Suppose I want to run Emacs as emacs -Q --script publish.el, where publish.el is a script that takes care of generating a website I am building. This script should read some org files and convert them to html. My intention is to write something like :grid: full in the org file, so that the corresponding html file has a <body class="full">. How can I do that?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

[Edit: added a filter implementation. Derived exporter is TBD (maybe?)]
The HTML exporter has no provision for adding attributes like class to the body tag. See the code: it adds the literal string <body> and does not allow the insertion of attributes.
There are two ways to do what you want:

the first one is through a filter. In particular, you can write a final-output filter that will be applied on the final HTML output; the filter should look for <body> and should replace it with <body class="full">. The manual page in the link contains some examples. You can also search this site: I used [org] final-output filter as a search string and came up with a bunch of matches - here is a simple one that removes attributes but it's very similar to what you want to do otherwise.

since the built-in exporter does not do what you want, you can write your own exporter. That is easier than you might think at first because your exporter is going to be mostly identical to the built-in HTML exporter with one change: the org-html-template function, which is what produces that undecorated <body> currently, will be overridden in your exporter by a new function that does what you want. Org mode provides a mechanism to write a so-called "derived" exporter that inherits most of its functionality from an existing exporter but overrides some functions of the existing exporter (in your case, just a single function: org-html-template). You can find an example of how to do this in this question - it concerns the LaTeX exporter, but the mods for the HTML exporter are essentially just changing latex to html (apart from the change to org-html-template which is very specific to this question).


It is a useful exercise to use one of these implementations to do what you want with a fixed string (e.g. "full"). As a second step, you can then implement the property value part of your question. The method shown in the answer to your previous question can be used to get the property value.

Here's an implementation of the filter solution in two stages: first, we use a fixed string for the class attribute and then we generalize to a property value. For testing, I prefer to have the code in my Org test file, in a babel block: when I make changes I just re-evaluate the babel block with C-c C-c to pick up the change. I can then export with C-c C-e h H and search for the <body ...> element in the HTML buffer to see what the function did. Once you have debugged the function, you can move the code to your init file.
Here's my test file:
* Link
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/81200/how-to-write-an-elisp-function-for-converting-org-files-to-html-with-custom-clas

* foo
bar


* Code                                                            :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/html-final-output-filter (text backend info)
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
             (replace-regexp-in-string "<body>" "<body class=\"full\">" text)))))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
               #'my/html-final-output-filter)
#+end_src

Note that the double quotes inside the string have to be escaped by prefixing a backslash to them.
Evaluate the code block with C-c C-c1 and then export with C-c C-e h H and look at the HTML buffer: you see <body class="full">.
The next step is to add the property2. Using org-property-values as indicated in the answer to your previous question (see link above), we now have this test file:
:PROPERTIES:
:html-body-class: full
:END:

* Link
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/81200/how-to-write-an-elisp-function-for-converting-org-files-to-html-with-custom-clas

* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:html-body-class: partial
:END:
bar


* Code                                                                                                        :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/html-final-output-filter (text backend info)
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
      ;; if there is an `html-class' property, get its value and add it
      ;; as a `class' attribute to the body element tag in the HTML.
      ;; Assumption: there is only one value for the property - if there
      ;; are more values than one, we arbitrarily select the *last*
      ;; value in the list that `org-property-values' returns, which is,
      ;; generally speaking, the *first* value encountered in the file,
      ;; but there are no guarantees: it is safer to make sure that the
      ;; value is unique.
      (let ((html-class (car (last (org-property-values "html-body-class")))))
        (if html-class
            (replace-regexp-in-string "<body>" (format "<body class=\"%s\">" html-class) text)))))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
               #'my/html-final-output-filter)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
(my/html-final-output-filter)
:end:

We get the value of the property and if it is non-nil, we create a body tag with the required class attribute. As I mentioned in your previous question, there might be multiple values for the property defined in the file and we need to choose one. After a bit of trial-and-error, I came up with the algorithm shown - see the comment in the code for an explanation.
Ideally, the value of the property would be obtained early in the export process and would be passed down through the info variable (that's how most settings are passed), but that requires more mechanism than I can go into here, so I cheated a bit and got the value at the end of the export process behind the exporter's back: read the code in ox.el and ox-html.el to see how it "should" be done.

Footnotes
[1] Note that the add-to-list is done every time you evaluate the block, but add-to-list checks the list and does not add duplicates, i.e. it is idempotent - I don't care about the minor inefficiency. If you care, put the add-to-list in a separate block and evaluate it only once after the first evaluation of the block that defines the function.
[2] Note that I call the property html-body-class. I didn't like the name grid and I certainly did not like the colon: there are far too many colons in a property definition as it is: adding another one is asking for trouble.

Thank you very much! I was able to implement your suggestions and achieved the desired effect. Once again, thank you for your time!
